# How to return glm::vec3 as a value?

Tags: c++, glm-math, return-value-optimization

I am trying to convert an array of floats to glm vector in a helper function. Unfortunately, the returned value is mangled:

```
arr: 1, 1, 0
fn.arr: 1, 1, 0
fn.vec: 1, 1, 0
vec: 4.7468e-11, 4.55856e-41, 1
```

I would expect the following code to allocate `vec` on stack in the function and then return it as a value.

```cpp
// main.cpp

float colour[3] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
std::cout << "arr: " << colour[0] << ", " << colour[1] << ", " << colour[2] << std::endl;
glm::vec3 c = arr_to_vec3(colour);
std::cout << "vec: " << c.x << ", " << c.y << ", " << c.z << std::endl;

// util.cpp

glm::vec3 arr_to_vec3(float arr[3]) {
  std::cout << "fn.arr: " << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1] << ", " << arr[2] << std::endl;
  glm::vec3 vec = glm::vec3(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
  std::cout << "fn.vec: " << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z << std::endl;

  return vec;
}
```

From the output above, it does not seem to be the case. Something must be deallocating the value as the last output shows random junk. Maybe the `float`s are not copied for some reason and the returned vector points to the `arr_to_vec3`’s stack frame? It is not really clear to me how the [data](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.8.5/glm/detail/type_vec3.hpp#L27-L76) is stored in the vector and what semantics applies.

Weirdly, I cannot reproduce if I just copy these two code blocks into an empty project (perhaps the memory is not cleared there by chance).

Comment: "Weirdly, I cannot reproduce if I just copy these two code blocks into an empty project" this sounds like undefined behaviour or other problems in other parts of your code. It is likely that the problem is not caused by the code you posted here